# Naming files in R loop

Tags: r, loops, audio

I have multiple audio files which are held in several subfolders in my working directory. I have a loop which reads in the first minute of each file and then saves them as a new file.

```
library(tuneR)

dir.create("New files")

FILES<-list.files(PATH, pattern = "audio", recursive = TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(FILES)){
  OneMIN <- readWave(FILES[i], from = 0, to = 60, units = "seconds")
  writeWave(OneMIN, filename = (file=paste0(FILES[i], "_1-min.wav")))
}
```

Now, there are a couple of things wrong with this;

1) The new files are called e.g. "File1.wav_1-min.wav", so that I need to rename them to "File_1-min.wav"

2) The new files are in multiple subfolders, and I have to then copy them to the "New files" folder using additional steps outside the loop.

I have workarounds to resolve these issues, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, by including additional lines in the loop. I would like to:

1) Strip out the first '.wav' in the file name

2) Automatically save them to the "New files" folder

However, I don't have an idea about how to go about this. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `fillesOut <- sub("\\.wav$", "", FILES)` should work for the first part. `paste0("./NewFiles/", filesOut[i], "_1-min.wav")` should get the second. Also see `dir.create` for creating directories in R, though if this is a one-off, you might just do it manually. Also `exists` for checking the existence of an object.

Comment: @lmo, the first part works nicely, but for the second I get an error; `Error in file(filename, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "wb") :
  cannot open file './Newfiles/2017-01-05/File1_1 min.wav': No such file or directory`

Comment: Take a look at the latter part of my comment. See `?dir.create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file.path()` function can be used to combined directories and filenames into a single filepath, while the `sub()` function will allow you to easily modify the filenames:

```
library(tuneR)

dir.create("New files")

FILES <- list.files(PATH, pattern = "audio", recursive = TRUE)

for(infile in FILES){
  OneMIN <- readWave(infile, from = 0, to = 60, units = "seconds")
  outfile <- file.path("New files", sub('.wav', '_1-min.wav', infile))
  writeWave(OneMIN, filename=outfile)
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that in the original code sample, the `list.files()` function will only return the filename part of each filepath.

Thus, you may need to modify your code to look something like:

```
FILES <- list.files(PATH, pattern = "audio", recursive = TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
```

and:

```
outfile <- file.path("New files", sub('.wav', '_1-min.wav', basename(infile)))
```

This will ensure that both `infile` and `outfile` are pointing to the correct locations.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would post my solution, which borrows from both @Keith Hughitt 's answer and @lmo 's comments. Thanks to both of them for helping work out what I needed.

```
for(i in 1:length(FILES)){
 OneMIN <- readWave(FILES[i], from = 0, to = 60, units = "seconds")
 FILE.OUT <- sub("\\.wav$", "_1 min.wav", FILES)
 OUT.PATH <- file.path("New files", basename(FILE.OUT))
 writeWave(OneMIN, filename = OUT.PATH[i])
}
```

As both implied, I was getting errors because of issues with the paths. I didn't need `full.names = TRUE` in the `FILES` assignment, but I did need to include `basename()` in the loop.

As Keith demonstrated in his answer, the `FILE.OUT` line is not strictly necessary, but it helps me to keep track of the different steps.