# Looping a command to an entire directory

Tags: r, file, loops

I have to convert a large number of audio files from .wav format to .flac format in order to save storage space on our server. The code for doing this on a single file looks like this:

```
wav2flac("TestFile.wav", reverse = FALSE, overwrite = FALSE,
         exename = "flac.exe", path2exe = "C:/Program Files/FLAC/flac-1.3.2- 
         win/win64")
```

How do I loop the command to perform on an entire directory of these .wav files?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723354/naming-files-in-r-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If the files are all in the same folder and in that folder there are only the files you need, then you can use `list.files` to find out all their paths then sapply to loop over them

```
files = list.files('C:/Yourfolderhere', full.names = T)
sapply(files, wav2flac, reverse = FALSE, overwrite = FALSE, exename = "flac.exe", path2exe = "C:/Program Files/FLAC/flac-1.3.2- win/win64")
```